# How can I get the text out of a textarea tag using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extract the text out of a textarea tag that doesn't display the value/text in it's html. I can't share the link/data since it's confidential but I'm certain I'm locating the correct textarea. My code to extract the text is as follows -

`x = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ace_text-input").get_attribute('value')`

When I attempt to print out the x variable, I receive an empty line. I have also tried to use .text and it gives me the same result. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share relevant HTML ?

Comment: @cruisepandey `<textarea class="ace_text-input" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" style="opacity: 0; left: 225.434px; top: 56px; height: 16px; width: 7.20125px;"></textarea>`

Comment: okay I will ask if you see any iframe parent/ancestor tag to this textarea ?

Comment: @cruisepandey There doesn't seem to be any iframe parent/ancestor tags

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste  and see `//textarea[@class='ace_text-input']` if your desired element is getting highlighted. also is there 1/1 matching node ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes to both questions

Comment: okay, if it is in Selenium view port then my solution should work for you. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
x = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ace_text-input").text
```

?
This works in most cases.
Or maybe

```
x = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ace_text-input").get_attribute("textContent"))
```

or

```
x = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ace_text-input").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

but the first one should work in most cases

Comment: None of these seem to be working, I get the empty line again

Answer (score 0):

May be your script need a explicit wait :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.ace_text-input"))).text)

or 

print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.ace_text-input"))).get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1 :**

```
x = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ace_text-input")
y = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].text;", x)
print(y)
```

Comment: This seems to throw a TimeOutException

Comment: @AhanSahu : Can you try with updated 1 code above ?

Comment: It returns None now, although there is definitely text in the textarea

Comment: Not sure, you can try with `.value` or `.textContent` in place of `.text` for above updated 1 code.